# remove the instance while uninstall msi package

Tags: sql-server

I have uninstalled the XYZ.msi package from Control Panel.It is completely uninstalled,but it's instance is still available in SQL server 2005.Why the instance didn't remove after uninstall of the package?I want to remove that instance.Is any possibilities to remove the instance in SQL server while uninstalling the msi package?

Comment: may be you uninstalled the wrong package! for SQL Server 2005 look for the name "Microsoft SQL Serve 2005" in the "uninstall or change a program menu" and uninstall it.